# Slider not working in Firefox?

Tags: image, firefox, slider

I am working on this site and deiced to created a slider (using some source code I found form the internet) which can be seen here http://gpsfac.co.uk/

It seems to work fine in chrome, safari etc but in firefox it seems to hide all the links at the bottom and enlarge the images? Anyone know why this may be and a quick fix?...

Thank you

Comment: put your code on fiddle, then we will able to help you.

Comment: Cant the code be seen from viewing the source code on the website?

Comment: It seem working fine in firefox also when i open your given link. So i am unable to understand your problem. please check this:http://prntscr.com/6eyi1z

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer all I Need to do was state the width % at 100% in the style css...